# Как грамотно скрывать поля у узла итерируемого объекта?

Tags: c++

Есть класс(хэш таблица). В этой таблице есть итератор, который бегает по элементам таблицы - Нодам(Node). Для удобства работы внутри класса, сам служебный класс Node объявлен как `protected`. Но поля у этой ноды все `public`. Я запускаю цикл foreach по этой таблице. Этот цикл предоставляет мне на каждой итерации очередную ноду, но вот проблема - у ноды открыты поля, которые желательно скрыть вне класса(но часть полей нужно оставить для доступа из цикла). Но внутри класса они должны быть `public`, иначе поля этого служебного класса не будут видны производным классам. От туда и вопрос, как скрыть часть полей этой ноды при обходе `foreach` циклом? Пробовал обертки делать, но там разврат получался.

Побочный вопрос: почему `foreach` цикл может работать с нодами, если они объявлены как `protected` класс? Вне цикла их нельзя вызывать, как и должно быть.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Comment: @tocic там дело в том, что производный класс находится в отдельном заголовочном файле. И чтобы ```friend``` работал, нужно заголовок с производным классом поместить над базовым, получиться цикл. Разве не стоит избегать таких вещей? (мы не говорим сейчас про возможность использовать препроцессор)

Comment: @tocic и, такой вопрос, а как это на производный класс все же сделать? Я побаловался и чет методы производного класса не видят поля.

Comment: Не очень понял проблему. [Вот](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/9d31d1c214e0f010fbb12ecb1780ac27dab6e435/libcxx/include/unordered_map#L959), посмотрите, как в том же libc++ сделано.

Comment: @tocic как я понял, тут все в одном файле реализовано, у меня другая ситуация. В одном заголовочном базовый класс лежит, в другом производный.

Comment: Так, я понял, как это поправить. Правда сейчас вылазят доп. упущения. Например, в моем случае класс Node - служебный класс базового класса, поэтому и друзья его должны находится в локале базового класса, если я правильно понял теорию. Поэтому я попробовал ноду вынести из класса и вот тогда все заработало хорошо. Но хочется ноду внутри держать...